Why is my text color not applying when using Tailwind CSS CDN?
I have been trying to get started with tailwind css using it's play CDN.

I created a sample index.html with a smalple tailwindcss usage
I linked it with cdn

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Tailwind CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Colors</title>
    <style> 
      body {
        padding: 5rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. Colors With Different Shades -->
    <!-- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors  -->

    <h1 class="text-green-500">1.Color With Differant Shades</h1>
    <p>TailWind</p>
  </body>
</html>


it should make the text green. but it's not working. it still black

Seems to be working in this JSFiddle which would suggest it is something particular to your enviornment/machine that is causing the unexpected behavior.
